# Why is changing the font size also changing the height of the div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I want to fill with an icon. However, even though I've set the div size to a set value, it still resizes. I guess I understand why it resizes when I make the content larger (although I thought it would just cut off the extra material), but I definitely don't understand why the div is getting bigger when I make the text *smaller*.

```css
//functional
#descriptionContainer {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: table-row;
}

#descriptionIcon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  display: table-cell;
}

#descriptionText {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: justify;
}

//broken
#descriptionContainer2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: table-row;
}

#descriptionIcon2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 5px; //why does this change the size of the div
}

#descriptionText2 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div id="descriptionContainer">
  <div id="descriptionIcon">
    test test test test
  </div>
  <div id="descriptionText">
    this is functional
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="descriptionContainer2">
  <div id="descriptionIcon2">
    test test test test
  </div>
  <div id="descriptionText2">
    this is not functional
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your div element with the text is set to `display: table-cell`. This means that the element has [**`vertical-align: baseline`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align), by default.

When you change the font size, this shifts the baseline of the text div within the container. That, I believe, is the reason for the shifting size of the box: *The baseline is jumping around.*

To prevent the re-sizing, set the `vertical-align` property to something else.

Try `vertical-align: middle`.

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0meo30eL/)

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you! One more quick question: why can I not set the overflow to hidden?

Comment: Because the `overflow` property only works on block-level elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow